# Nested Display Templates In Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm currently getting to grips with ASP.Net MVC 3 and the Razor templating engine, but I've come across an issue that I can't quite get to grips with - so over to the StackOverflow community to help!

Let's say that I have a View Model hierarchy that looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public string FooTitle { get; set; }
    [UIHint("BarList")]
    public IList<Bar> BarList { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public string BarTitle { get; set; }
}
```

all fairly simple I'm sure you'll agree. To go with this View Model I have the following:

**~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@model Foo

<h1>@Model.FooTitle</h1>
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BarList)
```

**~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/BarList.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Bar>

<div class="bar-list">
@Html.DisplayForModel()
</div>
```

**~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/Bar.cshtml**

```
@model Bar

<p>@Model.BarTitle</p>
```

I would expect to find the contents of `Bar.cshtml` to be displayed when I execute my View, but the rendering doesn't seem to nest further that `BarList.cshtml`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the intermediary `BarList.cshtml` template nor `UIHint` if you follow the conventions:

```
public class Foo {
    public string FooTitle { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> BarList { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public string BarTitle { get; set; }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model Foo
<h1>@Model.FooTitle</h1>
<div class="bar-list">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BarList)
</div>
```

Display template (`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/Bar.cshtml`):

```
@model Bar
<p>@Model.BarTitle</p>
```

and the `Bar.cshtml` template will automatically be rendered for each element of the `BarList` collection.

Comment: I know this, but I have a situation where I want to re-use the list in different views that belong to this controller, and I don't want to have to have to specify the enclosing <div></div> every time

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you still have this issue but this is the correct solution

**~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/BarList.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Bar>
<div class="bar-list">
@foreach (var bar in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(c => bar)
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all these Display Templates to:
~/Views/**Shared**/DisplayTemplates/

Edit: What about iterating through each bar?

```
@model IEnumerable<Bar>
<div class="bar-list">
@foreach (var bar in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayForModel(bar)
}
</div>
```

Comment: Moving the templates to Shared as opposed to the specific view does not resolve my question.

Comment: Strange. I've done literally the exact same thing in my app and it works fine.  Try the code above